# How do you use ICs in your own projects that don't come with a datasheet?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

Is it possible to use ICs in your own projects that don't come with a datasheet, by reverse engineering or ordering the datasheet somewhere, for example the IMX260 CMOS image sensor from the Galaxy S7?

[image]

I mean the IMX260, the [L2G2IS](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/6f/7d/9c/da/78/f2/42/1b/DM00150082.pdf/files/DM00150082.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00150082.pdf) gyroscope and [W25Q32FW][www.winbond.com/resource-files/da00-w25q32fwa1.pdf] serial flash memory chips on the left of the camera actually have public datasheet.

Comment: The phrase "you're on your own" applies.

Comment: What does "use" mean here? Do you intend to remove one or more chips from the camera module and use them elsewhere? Or you asking how to use the camera module that happens to have an undocumented chip (or three) in it?  Are you asking "how do I use this camera module", or are you asking specifically about the Sony IMX260. Chips like that are sophisticated OEM products that are not sold on the open market. The data sheets are not released to the public, but only to OEM customers.

Comment: Yeah, additionally some jurisdictions have laws against reverse engineering stuff, especially if it contains any kind of copy protection.  I would scour the net looking for others that have tackled the same project.  Clean room reverse engineering is still legal in most places but be careful of publishing data that you got from a random source if it could contain trade secrets, you may have to explain how you came about such stuff.  However hooking up a suitable analyser and sniffing the signals is a valid though sometimes slow process.

Comment: @KalleMP I don't think it is easy to find a company to reverse engineer something as sophisticated as the mentioned camera module however. Do you have any suggestion for reverse engineering companies that could do this or suitable analysers?

Answer (score 3):

> How do you use ICs in your own projects that don't come with a datasheet?

I don't.  That would be irresponsible engineering.  Putting something in the field that you don't really know all the specifications and requirements of is very risky.

OK, so you get the prototype to work on your bench.  That only means you got that one board working.  Maybe you tested it over a range of supply voltages, but what about temperature, humidity, certain sequences that may require specific timing to other things?

The real problem is you can't even know all the parameters that matter.  And even if you did, getting a sample of one to work only means it's possible, not that it will always work.  How do you know that your unit is a little more tolerant of some key parameter that you happen to be on the edge of?  And remember, you don't even know what all the key parameters are, so you can't say you've added margin to everything.  Even then, how much margin is enough to account for unit to unit variation, variations over time, temperature, humidity, vibration, handling history, etc, etc, etc.

Worst case you're close but not quite there.  The first 20 prototypes you send to beta sites work great.  They only had a 1:5 chance of hitting the 1:100 error, and this batch didn't happen to hit it.

After you have 1000 units in the field, you've got 10 customers all around the world complaning that your crappy box doesn't work.  The other 990 customers are fine and don't make any noise, but nobody hears them.  Those contemplating buying your product see ten separate bad reviews, and immediately cross your company off the list.  This will stick in their mind, and they won't buy other products from your company either.  Of course nobody tells you why they skipped over your product, they just silently buy someone else's product.  Then two out of the ten customers with bad units go out of their way to make a stink on the internet.

If management is clueless, the company will slowly coast to a stop and you lose your job.  If management has someone competent getting to the bottom of this, you'll be fired for incompetence and you still lose your job, and a track record of irresponsible engineering follows you around.  You are forced to find a new career and now ask *"Do you want fries with that?"* for a living.

Don't be that loser.

Comment: The components themselves could be very reliable however, as they have gone through a lot of testing already, as for the s7, you can find many stress tests such drop, freeze and boil tests they survived on YouTube and they sold 26 million units in only 4 months and are widely praised. And if you only want to make a few of them (and not a few hundreds or thousands), this would be reliable enough.

Comment: @Cigma: YouTube is not the basis for any kind of real engineering.  Yes, you can get away with it, sometimes.  It's a probability game, but in this case you don't know the probabilities nor the rules of the game.  Downvote as you like, but the OP asked what *I* would do, and that's what I answered.

Comment: Well put .Maybe you could have been a great writer .+1. I have been drumming this into young graduate engineers fresh out of college.The way you put things is very useful.